# how to access in an anonymous function variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can't access to the local variable in a anonymous function. So what is the proper way to do that in the below code? What I'm trying to do is when something is typed  in the input field then it'll multiply with a value then I need to add it in a variable named total . so what's wrong here with this code?

```
$('#menu input').on('click', function () {
    total = 0;

    //if checkbox with id menu1 is checked
    if ($("input#menu1").is(':checked')) {

    var name = 'menu1';

    $.post('DB.php', {name: name}, function (data) {
        //data is integer value retrieved from the database exmp: data = 200
        $('input#box1price').val(data);

        // multiplying total
        price1 = parseInt(data);
        $('input#box1quantity').keyup(function(){
            q = $(this).val();
            quantity = parseInt(q);
            price1Total = quantity * price1;
            $('input#box1total').val(price1Total);
        });

        total = price1Total; //it's saying price1Total is undefined

        $('#total').show();
        $('#total').text(total);
    });
}
```

Comment: you never defined `price1Total` when doing `total = price1Total;`

Comment: Keyup function is not called until keyup event while `total = price1Total` is run just after you create the keyup event listener

Comment: @Hacketo even I define price1Total, it always gets the undefined value but I need to override it when it's keyup even is triggered .

Comment: @monir009 then you have to re-execute the part of your code that use `price1Total` when its value change. to do so you can move that code in a function and call that function with `price1Total` as parameter

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you should **always** declare your variables.

Second, in that case, you must declare it outside the annonymous function, and then use it inside it.

```
$.post('DB.php', {name: name}, function (data) {
       //data is integer value retrieved from the database exmp: data = 200
        $('input#box1price').val(data);

        // multiplying total
        var price1 = parseInt(data);
        var price1Total = 0;

        $('input#box1quantity').keyup(function() {
            var q = $(this).val();
            var quantity = parseInt(q);
            price1Total = quantity * price1;
            $('input#box1total').val(price1Total);
        });

        var total = price1Total;

        $('#total').show();
        $('#total').text(total);
    });
}
```

Comment: no, it's not working , it's still getting total as undefined

Comment: @monir009 So, please, create a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) and simulate your problem there for us, so we can help you out.

Comment: Even here updating the total needs to be in the keyup event handler.  The line `var total = price1Total` is going to execute immediatedly after the keyup event handler is defined.  So `total` will always be 0.

Comment: @Tony Yeah, I know total will be always 0. The thing is: he has an `input#box1total` and a `#total`, and we have no idea what he's trying to accomplish. I guess he wants to show both at the begining and probably update both when someone changes the `input#box1quantity`. But his code is very weird, since he's declaring the `keyup` event inside the callback function, and apparently, he has no idea what he's doing. As soon as I can't help w/ everything, I've just focused in the question "how to access in an anonymous function variable?" and explained to him that he must declare the variables etc.

Comment: @Tony yeah, I think so. It needs to override the value when keyup event is triggered .  it's kind of related to database and another file that is written in php , so jsfiddle won't work perfectly I guess.

Comment: When you say total is undefined, are you checking via a `console.log` immediately after running `$.post`, or are you waiting for the AJAX method to complete (which the `$.post` method does **not**) and then checking it in the console?

Comment: yeah, it's via console.log , and I checked after the event is triggered.

Comment: what I'm trying to do is in first (menu1) input1 * input2 = total1 and same for menu2 then total1, total2 and total3 need to adding

Answer (score 0):

`price1Total` will always be undefined in that code.

It simply isn't possible for a keyup event to fire between the event handler being assigned as the `total = price1Total;` statement being evaluated.

You need to redesign your logic so it either does not depend on the keyup event or so that everything which does depend on that even takes place *inside* the event handler.

Comment: Step 1 is to define the problem. The code you have doesn't make any sense and I can't reverse engineer it to figure out what you are *trying* to achieve. Once you have defined what you want to do, you can figure out how to do it. Angular, at this point, sounds more like Go To Massively Complicated MVC Framework, Do Not Pass Go, Do Not Collect $200.

Answer (score -1):

The anonymous function which you have defined for `keyup()` callback is a closure which means it will be executing outside the global scope & the variable `total1price` is not defined in your code, which means JavaScript engine will declare this variable in global scope automatically.

Now the issue with your approach is that when you try to reference `total1price` variable outside the keyup closure/ callback function it will not be available because this variable will not be defined until the keyup handler is triggered hence  it will contain the default value `undefined` in it.

**How to fix the issue:**

Try moving the below line 
 `$('#total').show();
        $('#total').text(total1price);`
Inside the `keyup` event callback function, so that as soon as the value of  `total1price` is found the total value is updated on the DOM.

Comment: Your first paragraph is completely backwards. If you don't stick `var` on something then it will create a **global**.

Comment: I got  confused a bit anyway thanks for pointing out that, I have corrected it bro.